# jQueryUI Autocomplete data from text/csv file with $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've been trying to amend the example from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight to work with input from a locally stored text/csv file looking like

```
ItemA
ItemB
ItemC
....
```

I am able to create an array from the data in the textfile and print it to console.log() but I'm not sure how to hand over this array to the autocomplete function. I've tried initializing the array a outside the function but when using it in autocomplete it will use the non-populated array a.

```
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "john.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {processData(data);}
 });
});

var a = [];
function processData(myTxt) {
    var myLines = myTxt.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    for (var i=1; i<myLines.length; i++) {
          a.push(myLines[i]);
        }
        console.log(a);
}


$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: a
});
</script>
```

How do I pass the array correctly to autocomplete?

Comment: The `console.log(a)` gives correct array output... right?

Comment: Yes. But if I put the console.log(a) outside of the function it returns [] so I guess my entire code structure is a bit crooked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to add autocomplete source before the AJAX query is completed.

The query is done on `$(document).ready()` but the autocomplete source is set before it. So a still remains empty.

Try this:

```
var a = [];
function processData(myTxt) {
    var myLines = myTxt.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    for (var i=1; i<myLines.length; i++) {
          a.push(myLines[i]);
        }
        console.log(a);
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: a
        });
}
```